# Reading through a folder of Files?

Tags: python, file, list, python-3.x

I am assigned to write a program that catches plagiarists. Given a folder of files, how would I iterate through them file-by-file, constructing a list of all 6-word phrases in each file. An example of this is

Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.

Contains the 6-word phrases: 
Now is the time for all, 
is the time for all good, 
the time for all good men,
time for all good men to, 
...and so on.

```
ExampleFile=F.read('File')
index1=0
index2=5
List1=[]
while True:
     index1+=1
     index2+=1
     List1+= Examplefile[index1:index2]
```

Is what I have so far to create the lists of 6 word phrases. How then would I go about doing this for each file and then comparing those results to see if any two files have over 200 of the same phrases? I have done very little with using files in Python so dumb everything down as much as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since it's homework, I think a couple of links will help you more than complete code.

Take a look at [`os.listdir`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) that lists all files in a folder and [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) that traverses a directory tree.

Then you can make a list where each item is a container of phrases. I suggest using a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) of phrases for each file, and a list of such sets, or maybe a `set` of `frozenset`s.

Then you can take all pairwise combinations of those sets with [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and compute the [intersection](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection) for each pair. If the size of any intersection is above the threshold, you've found the plagiarist.

---

A comment on your current code: there is a naming convention that variable names should start with lowercase letters, and capitalized names are used for classes.